# Why does Java 8 Decrypt File AES/CBC/NoPadding generate another encryted file?

Tags: java, encryption, java-8, aes

I have this aes-128-cbc algorithm of encryption to decrypt an encrypted file. According to this [Cipher link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), the correct Cipher instance is: AES/CBC/NoPadding, I have this method.

```
private static void decrypt() {
    String key = "12345678";
    String inputFile = "src/main/resources/config/data.encrypted";
    String outputFile = "src/main/resources/config/data";

    try {
        // Read the encrypted file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) fis.available()];
        fis.read(inputBytes);

        // Set up the decryption cipher
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        // Decrypt the file
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

        // Write the decrypted file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        osw.write(new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        fis.close();
        osw.close();

        System.out.println("File decrypted successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I've gotten that, the resulting file is encrypted. Would you please give me any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @sinanspd: what does `fis.available()` have to do with it? The IV is `new byte[16]` and that is _always_ 16 bytes of zero. While you do want to use the same IV as encrypt did, using a different (wrong) IV in CBC decrypt corrupts only the first block; everything else would still be okay -- except maybe the last few bytes, because NoPadding is almost never correct. OP: unless your 'data' is actually valid characters, decoding it as UTF8 and then reencoding it will destroy about half of it, so don't do that.

Comment: Why use a `Writer`? Use an `OutputStream` to write it. Otherwise you are getting into character conversion issues. NB (1) `InputStream.read()` isn't specified to fill the buffer, and (2) `fis.available()` isn't specified as returning the size of the file. Use `File.length()` for that. And have a look at `CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream`. Rather than trying to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: I do not see that your decryption method will work ever as you are using an eight bytes long AES key. Key length for AES is 16, 24 or 32 bytes. Btw: your encryption scheme is high graded **unsecure** as you are using a fixed initializing vector (IV), please use a random IV and a key derivation like PBKDF2 if you are been able to change the Encryption part.

Answer (score 1):

We *cannot* indicate why decryption fails. CBC without unpadding (which is implied for `"NoPadding"` will *always succeed as long as the input data is a multiple of the block size.* The decryption algorithm would just run its course without throwing any exception.

Errors could include:

1. Any change to the ciphertext;
2. A wrong IV;
3. A different cipher or cipher mode used during encryption;
4. An incorrect key value.

Now a change to the ciphertext (1) will likely keep some part of the resulting plaintext intact. A wrong IV for CBC mode (2) will just randomize the first part of the resulting plaintext. Errors with a different mode (3) may give any kind of weird result and using a wrong key (4) will create a whole new level of encryption (unless it creates an exception if a different  mode is used). For many modes of operation decryption is very similar or even identical to encryption.

You have indicated that "the resulting file is encrypted" but this isn't certain as any error listed above will at least result in *some* of the decrypted ciphertext to be randomized. Symmetric ciphers are designed to create ciphertext that is indistinguishable from random data. If any part of the data is not randomized then problems 1 or 2 are most likely.